# How to fetch only text from html links using cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Hello I have a webpage which has an HTML like this

```
<div class="css-content">
   <div class="css-2aj">
      <img src="" >
      <div data-bn-type="text" id="/48" class="">Latest News</div>
   </div>
   <div class="css-6f9">
      <div class="css-content">
         <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/523hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">US could be on cusp of new Covid surge</a>

         <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/423hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">Stop sharing your vaccine cards on social media</>
            <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/2222hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">Italians can be fined up to $60,000 for selling the world's 'most dangerous' cheese</a>

         <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/2223hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">The Masked Singer' reveals the identity of The Phoenix<a/>

        
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want results this way

- US could be on cusp of new Covid surge
- Italians can be fined up to $60,000 for selling the world's 'most
  dangerous' cheese
- The Masked Singer' reveals the identity of The Phoenix

This is what I have tried

```
    var list = [];
$('div[class="css-6f9"]').find('div  > a').each(function (index, element) {
    list.push($(element).attr('href'));
});


console.log(list);
```

the result is empty array

I am completely new here and no idea how to fetch the result which is in `<a></a>` tags
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

don't require `cheerio` as `$`

```js
const html = `<div class="css-content">
<div class="css-2aj">
   <img src="" >
   <div data-bn-type="text" id="/48" class="">Latest News</div>
</div>
<div class="css-6f9">
   <div class="css-content">
      <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/523hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">US could be on cusp of new Covid surge</a>

      <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/423hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">Stop sharing your vaccine cards on social media</>
         <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/2222hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">Italians can be fined up to $60,000 for selling the world's 'most dangerous' cheese</a>

      <a data-bn-type="link" href="/en/blog/news/2223hshhshhshhs3331adc0" class="css-1ej">The Masked Singer' reveals the identity of The Phoenix<a/>

     
   </div>
</div>
</div>`;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
let list = [];
$('.css-content > a').each(function () {
  list.push($(this).text().trim());
});
console.log(list.filter((item) => Boolean(item)));
```

[image]

Comment: Its not working. I guess the reason there is there are two divs with the same css name 'css-content' as you can see in the code. And scripting is picking the first one and based on first one there is no href tag under it. Please check

Comment: still empty array

Comment: @mynameisbutt I've updated my answer, and note that there two extra `undefined` value in the list, that's because the html string has some invalid parts, such as `...media</>`

Comment: Thank you . But its printing the URLs. i need the content. Please check the question

Comment: @mynameisbutt just change `attr('href')` to `text()`, same as jQuery api, good luck